# Create pdf in Android, setBorderColor

Tags: android, itext, itextg

I use `iText` library to create pdf, in Java Project `setBorderColor` work, I use:

```
c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("182-432-23-23",smallFontBold));
c1.setBorderColor(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
```

but in Android Project in this code I have error:

```
c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("182-432-23-23",smallFontBold));
c1.setBorderColor(Color.GRAY);
```

error:

```
The method setBorderColor(Color) in the type Rectangle is not applicable for the arguments (int)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `Color.GRAY` is an `int` value, whereas the `setBorderColor()` method expects an instance of the `BaseColor` class. What type of object is `Color`? There is no such class in iText and `java.awt.Color` is forbidden on Android (as are all AWT classes).

Try:

```
c1.setBorderColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
c1.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
c1.setBorderWidth(1);
```

I added the two extra lines just to make sure that there *is* a border; setting the color if no border needs to be drawn has no effect.

**Important:** if you are using a version of iText that doesn't have a `BaseColor` class, then you are using the wrong version of iText. On Android, you need to use [iTextG](http://www.itextpdf.com/product/itextg).

Answer (score 0):

try Hash code or Other code then Color.GRAY. May it help you,

As your Error says  `Rectangle is not applicable for the arguments (int)`

Comment: Error says that Your color code should be Integer. So Try Different Color Code in it.